# Use hmac.new() in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

How can I use this function:

```
def generate_sig(endpoint, params, secret):
sig = endpoint
for key in sorted(params.keys()):
    sig += '|%s=%s' % (key, params[key])
return hmac.new(secret, sig, sha256).hexdigest()
```

with these parameters:

```
endpoint = '/media/657988443280050001_25025320'
params = {
'access_token': 'fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d',
'count': 10,
}
secret = '6dc1787668c64c939929c17683d7cb74'
```

In Python 3? Now I receive this error:

```
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

Comment: Your secret needs to be ```b'6dc1787668c64c939929c17683d7cb74'``` to be compatible with *bytes*. This might be needed for access_token too (and maybe endpoint?).

Comment: If I use the 'b' prefix to the access_token and secret strings I receive this error: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing.
If I use the 'b' prefix to all the 3 strings I receive this error: TypeError: can't concat bytes to str.

Comment: Because of your ```sig += ...```. Read up python's docs on bytes and strings (as you are mixing them here). And don't post incomplete errors as your stack-trace will probably tell you that exactly this line is the source of the error.

Comment: What is the use of the operator '%'?

Comment: String-formatting (again: python-docs). Don't use copy-pasted code without understanding it. This is even more important when doing crypto!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
def generate_sig(endpoint, params, secret):
    sig = endpoint
    for key in sorted(params.keys()):
        sig += '|%s=%s' % (key, params[key])
    return hmac.new(bytes(secret,encoding='ascii'), 
                    bytes(sig,encoding='ascii'), 
                    sha256).hexdigest()
```

This way you encode like *bytes* only to get the hash.